# Why do the use of > in this code produce an error?

Tags: python, counting, items

Trying to use the `.get` function in a dictionary.

I have not tried much, as I do not know that much yet.

```
name = input("Enter file: ")
handle = open(name)
counts = dict()
for line in handle:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1

bigcount = None
bigword = None
for word, count in counts.items():
    if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
        bigcount = word
        bigword = count
```

I get this result:

```
 if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

What it should produce is a number. What is wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that `word` is a string and I see in your for loop you have `bigcount = word`, so now `bigcount` is a string also. Next time round the loop `count > bigcount` is comparing `int` and `str`.

Comment: I think your last two assignments are backwards. You're assigning your `int` and `str` to the wrong variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `collections.Counter` instead of re-implementing it, you won't have the opportunity to make such an error.

```
from collections import Counter


counts = Counter()
name = input("Enter file: ")
with open(name) as handle:
    for line in handle:
        counts.update(line.split())

bigword, bigcount = counts.most_common(1)[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have your assignments backwards. You're actually using `.get` correctly.

```
bigcount = None
bigword = None
for word, count in counts.items():
    if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
        bigcount = count     # Switched these two
        bigword = word
```

Comment: I have tried switching those you mentioned, it still produces the same traceback. Or maybe I don´t do it correctly.

Comment: if bigcount is None or bigcount > count